# Storing Class Instances In A Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, hashtable

I have class Foo.  Foo has a property of public string x.

I would like to instantiate Foo a few times as ONE and TWO, and add those instances to Hashtable Bar with keys 1 and 2 respectively.  How do I obtain string x for the particular instance.

I've tried something to the like of:  Bar[1].x, but the property x is not recognized.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `Dictionary<int, Foo>` instead of `Hashtable`.  `Hashtable` is an obsolete class for the days we didn't have generics. It stores key and values as `object` type. `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, on the other hand, is a strongly typed generic collection.

If you want to use `Hashtable` for some reason (e.g. C# 1.0), you'll have to cast the object:

```
 ((Foo)Bar[1]).x
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to cast once oyu retrieve from the Hashtable. Try:
string s = (myHashtable[myKey] as Foo).x;

Arg! Just saw Mehrdad Afshari's answer, which correctly points this out

Comment: Re your usage of "as", see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-as-operator-so-popular/2139818#2139818

Comment: As far as using "as", that was just a quick line.. I'll leave the decision of using "as" or the direct cast to the reader as an exercise, but thank Mehrdad for the valuable link