# Using "as" and expecting a null return

Tags: c#

For example.  Lets say we have a stackpanel on a form.  Its full of both Grids and Labels.  I want to loop through all the Grids and do some operation on them but leave the Lables intact.  At the moment I am doing it this way.

```
foreach(UIElement element in m_stacker.Children)
{
    Grid block = element as Grid;
    if(block != null)
    {
      //apply changes here
    }
}
```

So i'm using the fact that "as" returns null if it cannot cast into the required type.  Is this an ok thing to do or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Actually, that's probably the most common use case for `as`.

Comment: Thanks for all the response guys.  I'll stick with "as" looks like its the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's the right way to do it (considering "applying changes" will need to use the cast result).

However, if you are not going to use the cast return value, you can simply use `is`.

Using `is` and then [casting again with the cast operator (parenthesis) is frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-as-operator-so-popular/2139818#2139818).

Answer (score 13):

What about [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)?

```
foreach( var grid  in m_stacker.Children.OfType<Grid>() ) { ... }
```

This will loop only over the children of type *Grid*, so no need to cast or check the type at all.

Comment: In fact, `OfType<T>()` is doing internally exactly the same. ;-)

Comment: @Oliver: but the code looks more readably and is shorter this way.

Comment: `OfType` is a good way to filter out elements of a type in a collection. However, if you want to do different things with different objects in a single collection (`var g = o as Grid; if (g != null) { /* do this */ } else { var c = o as Canvas; if (c != null) { /* do that */ } }`), you'll have to iterate the collection a few times with `OfType` -- and when you have a single object, rather than a collection, it's not a choice.

Comment: @Mehrdad: that is correct, thanks for pointing it out. But for this question the OP wants to get items of *one type* - and then `OfType` is appropriate.

Comment: Definitely. Just wanted to point out that `OfType` is not a *replacement* for `as`. It's kind of a replacement for a `foreach` **and** `as`.

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine. What you can do is however just use "is".

```
foreach(UIElement element in m_stacker.Children)
{
    if(element is Grid)
    {
      //apply changes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Only if you don't need access to properties and methods of `Grid`.

Comment: It's obvious you need to cast it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `block` as a `Grid` then this is exactly the right way to code it.

Checking using `is` (to my mind) produces less readable code as illustrated in the following two **bad** examples:

```
if (element is Grid)
{
    Grid block = element as Grid;
    // Do stuff
}

if (element is Grid)
{
    Grid block = (Grid)element;
    // Do stuff
}
```

**Don't do either of these**.

You're saying if element is a grid then cast it.

Comment: Code Analysis recommends don't do like you wrote. The best approach as it think to use operator `as` and check to `null`.

Comment: @abatishchev - Agreed - I was highlighting what you **shouldn't** do.

Comment: I agree. Although, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using 'is' I think 'as' is definitely better in most situations.

Comment: what's Code Analysis when it's at home?