# Try-catch speeding up my code?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, try-catch, performance-testing

I wrote some code for testing the impact of try-catch, but seeing some surprising results.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;

    long start = 0, stop = 0, elapsed = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    long temp = Fibo(1);

    for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        temp = Fibo(100);
        stop = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        elapsed = stop - start;
        avg = avg + ((double)elapsed - avg) / i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + avg);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static long Fibo(int n)
{
    long n1 = 0, n2 = 1, fibo = 0;
    n++;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = fibo;
        fibo = n1 + n2;
    }

    return fibo;
}
```

On my computer, this consistently prints out a value around 0.96..

When I wrap the for loop inside Fibo() with a try-catch block like this:

```
static long Fibo(int n)
{
    long n1 = 0, n2 = 1, fibo = 0;
    n++;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = fibo;
            fibo = n1 + n2;
        }
    }
    catch {}

    return fibo;
}
```

Now it consistently prints out 0.69... -- it actually runs faster! But why?

Note: I compiled this using the Release configuration and directly ran the EXE file (outside Visual Studio).

EDIT: [Jon Skeet's *excellent* analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928476/282110) shows that try-catch is somehow causing the x86 CLR to use the CPU registers in a more favorable way in this specific case (and I think we're yet to understand why). I confirmed Jon's finding that x64 CLR doesn't have this difference, and that it was faster than the x86 CLR. I also tested using `int` types inside the Fibo method instead of `long` types, and then the x86 CLR was as equally fast as the x64 CLR.

---

**UPDATE:** It looks like this issue has been fixed by Roslyn. Same machine, same CLR version -- the issue remains as above when compiled with VS 2013, but the problem goes away when compiled with VS 2015.

Comment: I would not use stopwatch: http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html

Comment: try to run it in debug within VS and see if any exception is thrown which would end up the for loop and change the timing and result...

Comment: Could you please try "catch (Exception e) {Console.WriteLine(e.Message);}" - I have a theory, that could be falsified by that. EDIT: I know this code is useless!

Comment: You might want to compare the IL for the `Fibo` method between the two cases.

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair as Henk has pointed out its a pretty useless benchmark test case, if the op has some other underlying issue he is trying to resolve by creating such a test it would arguably be a better question!

Comment: Are you running this on a 64 bit machine? Try catch, or try-except as I know it, does not carry the performance penalty it does on the 32 bit platform.

Comment: So, now "Swallowing Exceptions" passed from being a bad practice to a good performance optimization :P

Comment: @Random832 Do you mean it's checked without try-catch and unchecked with one? Is that your point?. I guess It's unchecked in both situations, but MSDN says, It depends on compiler options if not specified expliciltly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx. Anyway, waiting for Eric Lippert to answer this question.

Comment: @taras.roshko No, it'd be the same in both cases. The point is, if it's checked, then the code inside the try block can throw an exception, which I would hope the JIT would be smart enough to change to a simple jump into the catch block when everything's local.

Comment: @taras.roshko: While I don't wish to do Eric a disservice, this isn't really a C# question - it's a JIT compiler question. The ultimate difficulty is working out why the x86 JIT doesn't use as many registers without the try/catch as it does *with* the try/catch block.

Comment: @Luciano: not exactly.. However, adding random try..catch blocks certainly entered the list of things to try for performance improvements.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350264/try-catch-performance

Comment: Sweet, so if we nest these try catches we can go even faster right ?

Comment: What does "the problem goes away when compiled with VS 2015" mean? Does that mean that the try-catch-version is then _slower_? That's like when Initech found out Milton was fired months ago, but still got paid; then _fixed the problem_ by stopping his pay checks.

Answer (score 1140, accepted):

One of the [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) engineers who specializes in understanding optimization of stack usage took a look at this and reports to me that there seems to be a problem in the interaction between the way the C# compiler generates local variable stores and the way the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler does register scheduling in the corresponding x86 code. The result is suboptimal code generation on the loads and stores of the locals.

For some reason unclear to all of us, the problematic code generation path is avoided when the JITter knows that the block is in a try-protected region.

This is pretty weird. We'll follow up with the JITter team and see whether we can get a bug entered so that they can fix this.

Also, we are working on improvements for Roslyn to the C# and VB compilers' algorithms for determining when locals can be made "ephemeral" -- that is, just pushed and popped on the stack, rather than allocated a specific location on the stack for the duration of the activation. We believe that the JITter will be able to do a better job of register allocation and whatnot if we give it better hints about when locals can be made "dead" earlier.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, and apologies for the odd behaviour.

Comment: I’ve always wondered why the C# compiler generates so many extraneous locals. For example, new array initialisation expressions always generate a local, but is never necessary to generate a local. If it allows the JITter to produce measurably more performant code, perhaps the C# compiler should be a bit more careful about generating unnecessary locals...

Comment: @Timwi: Absolutely. In unoptimized code the compiler produces unnecessary locals with great abandon because they make debugging easier. In optimized code unnecessary temporaries should be removed if possible. Unfortunately we've had many bugs over the years where we accidentally de-optimized the temporary-elimination optimizer. The aforementioned engineer is completely re-doing from scratch all of this code for Roslyn, and we should as a result have much improved optimized behaviour in the Roslyn code generator.

Comment: Was there ever any movement on this issue?

Comment: It looks like Roslyn did fix it.

Answer (score 764):

Well, the way you're timing things looks pretty nasty to me. It would be much more sensible to just time the whole loop:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    Fibo(100);
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

That way you're not at the mercy of tiny timings, floating point arithmetic and accumulated error.

Having made that change, see whether the "non-catch" version is still slower than the "catch" version.

EDIT: Okay, I've tried it myself - and I'm seeing the same result. Very odd. I wondered whether the try/catch was disabling some bad inlining, but using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` instead didn't help...

Basically you'll need to look at the optimized JITted code under cordbg, I suspect...

EDIT: A few more bits of information:

- Putting the try/catch around just the `n++;` line still improves performance, but not by as much as putting it around the whole block
- If you catch a specific exception (`ArgumentException` in my tests) it's still fast
- If you print the exception in the catch block it's still fast
- If you rethrow the exception in the catch block it's slow again
- If you use a finally block instead of a catch block it's slow again
- If you use a finally block *as well as* a catch block, it's fast

Weird...

EDIT: Okay, we have disassembly...

This is using the C# 2 compiler and .NET 2 (32-bit) CLR, disassembling with mdbg (as I don't have cordbg on my machine). I still see the same performance effects, even under the debugger. The fast version uses a `try` block around everything between the variable declarations and the return statement, with just a `catch{}` handler. Obviously the slow version is the same except without the try/catch. The calling code (i.e. Main) is the same in both cases, and has the same assembly representation (so it's not an inlining issue).

Disassembled code for fast version:

```
 [0000] push        ebp
 [0001] mov         ebp,esp
 [0003] push        edi
 [0004] push        esi
 [0005] push        ebx
 [0006] sub         esp,1Ch
 [0009] xor         eax,eax
 [000b] mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax
 [000e] mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax
 [0011] mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax
 [0014] mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax
 [0017] xor         eax,eax
 [0019] mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax
*[001c] mov         esi,1
 [0021] xor         edi,edi
 [0023] mov         dword ptr [ebp-28h],1
 [002a] mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],0
 [0031] inc         ecx
 [0032] mov         ebx,2
 [0037] cmp         ecx,2
 [003a] jle         00000024
 [003c] mov         eax,esi
 [003e] mov         edx,edi
 [0040] mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp-28h]
 [0043] mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp-24h]
 [0046] add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h]
 [0049] adc         edx,dword ptr [ebp-24h]
 [004c] mov         dword ptr [ebp-28h],eax
 [004f] mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],edx
 [0052] inc         ebx
 [0053] cmp         ebx,ecx
 [0055] jl          FFFFFFE7
 [0057] jmp         00000007
 [0059] call        64571ACB
 [005e] mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h]
 [0061] mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-24h]
 [0064] lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]
 [0067] pop         ebx
 [0068] pop         esi
 [0069] pop         edi
 [006a] pop         ebp
 [006b] ret
```

Disassembled code for slow version:

```
 [0000] push        ebp
 [0001] mov         ebp,esp
 [0003] push        esi
 [0004] sub         esp,18h
*[0007] mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],1
 [000e] mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],0
 [0015] mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],1
 [001c] mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],0
 [0023] inc         ecx
 [0024] mov         esi,2
 [0029] cmp         ecx,2
 [002c] jle         00000031
 [002e] mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]
 [0031] mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
 [0034] mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax
 [0037] mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx
 [003a] mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]
 [003d] mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]
 [0040] mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax
 [0043] mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx
 [0046] mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
 [0049] mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
 [004c] add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]
 [004f] adc         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]
 [0052] mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax
 [0055] mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],edx
 [0058] inc         esi
 [0059] cmp         esi,ecx
 [005b] jl          FFFFFFD3
 [005d] mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]
 [0060] mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]
 [0063] lea         esp,[ebp-4]
 [0066] pop         esi
 [0067] pop         ebp
 [0068] ret
```

In each case the `*` shows where the debugger entered in a simple "step-into".

EDIT: Okay, I've now looked through the code and I think I can see how each version works... and I believe the slower version is slower because it uses fewer registers and more stack space. For small values of `n` that's possibly faster - but when the loop takes up the bulk of the time, it's slower.

Possibly the try/catch block *forces* more registers to be saved and restored, so the JIT uses those for the loop as well... which happens to improve the performance overall. It's not clear whether it's a reasonable decision for the JIT to *not* use as many registers in the "normal" code.

EDIT: Just tried this on my x64 machine. The x64 CLR is *much* faster (about 3-4 times faster) than the x86 CLR on this code, and under x64 the try/catch block doesn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Ok, tried your suggestion. And it still runs faster!  Ran each version 3 times with consistent results.  Without try-catch: 29.7s, with: 19.5s.

Comment: I am betting since re throwing the exception causes it to slow down again then there is some overhead from the function maintaining exception information, but since it is dealt with locally the overhead disappears unless the user re throws the exception.

Comment: @GordonSimpson but in the case where only a specific exception is caught then all other exceptions would not be caught, so whatever overhead was involved in your hypothesis for no-try would still be needed.

Comment: Turning off optimisations has an effect, but the try-catch version is still faster, so its' probably not any of the things that affects.

Comment: It looks like a difference in register allocation. The fast version manages to use `esi,edi` for one of the longs instead of the stack. It uses `ebx` as the counter, where the slow version uses `esi`.

Comment: I agree with  Jeffrey Sax, if you follow the code flow you can see that the slow version have more memory access that the fast version. But the question maintains.

Comment: @JeffreySax: It's not just *which* registers are used but how many. The slow version uses more stack space, touching fewer registers. I've no idea why...

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible that arithmetic operations are checked without try-catch and unchecked with try-catch?

Comment: @taras.roshko: No, definitely not. They're unchecked in both cases.

Comment: How are CLR exception frames dealt with in terms of registers and stack? Could setting one up have freed a register up for use somehow?

Comment: IIRC x64 has more registers available than x86.  The speedup you saw would be consistent with the try/catch forcing additional register use under x86.

Comment: Actually, instead of it being about the Try/Catch Block, it might be because of the block in this case. That might give the JIT just the information it needed to know that it could use more registers. Will have to try that.

Comment: @Rangoric: I'm not sure what you mean - there's already a block due to the for loop, for example.

Comment: @Jon IIRC the for loop's variable is outside the loop's block, meaning that try block is around more than just the loop.

Comment: @Rangoric I tried the block theory earlier and it didn't have an effect. I suspect that there may other configurations where it does though, on the basis of this.

Comment: @JonHanna Ok, it was just an idea based on how the assembly changed.

Comment: @Rangoric Yes, pretty much the same idea I'd had when I tried it :)

Answer (score 121):

Jon's disassemblies show, that the difference between the two versions is that the fast version uses a pair of registers (`esi,edi`) to store one of the local variables where the slow version doesn't.

The JIT compiler makes different assumptions regarding register use for code that contains a try-catch block vs. code which doesn't. This causes it to make different register allocation choices. In this case, this favors the code with the try-catch block. Different code may lead to the opposite effect, so I would not count this as a general-purpose speed-up technique.

In the end, it's very hard to tell which code will end up running the fastest. Something like register allocation and the factors that influence it are such low-level implementation details that I don't see how any specific technique could reliably produce faster code.

For example, consider the following two methods. They were adapted from a real-life example:

```
interface IIndexed { int this[int index] { get; set; } }
struct StructArray : IIndexed { 
    public int[] Array;
    public int this[int index] {
        get { return Array[index]; }
        set { Array[index] = value; }
    }
}

static int Generic<T>(int length, T a, T b) where T : IIndexed {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        sum += a[i] * b[i];
    return sum;
}
static int Specialized(int length, StructArray a, StructArray b) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        sum += a[i] * b[i];
    return sum;
}
```

One is a generic version of the other. Replacing the generic type with `StructArray` would make the methods identical. Because `StructArray` is a value type, it gets its own compiled version of the generic method. Yet the actual running time is significantly longer than the specialized method's, but only for x86. For x64, the timings are pretty much identical. In other cases, I've observed differences for x64 as well.

Comment: With that being said... can you force different register allocation choices without using a Try/Catch? Either as a test for this hypothesis or as a general attempt to tweak for speed?

Comment: There are a number of reasons why this specific case may be different. Maybe it's the try-catch. Maybe it's the fact that the variables are re-used in an inner scope. Whatever the specific reason is, it's an implementation detail that you can't count on to be preserved even if the exact same code is called in a different program.

Comment: @WernerCD I'd say the fact that C and C++ has a keyword for suggesting that which (A) is ignored by many modern compilers and (B) it was decided not to put in C#, suggests that this isn't something we'll see in any more direct way.

Comment: @WernerCD - Only if you write the assembly yourself

Answer (score 77):

This looks like a case of inlining gone bad.  On an x86 core, the jitter has the ebx, edx, esi and edi register available for general purpose storage of local variables.  The ecx register becomes available in a static method, it doesn't have to store *this*.  The eax register often is needed for calculations.  But these are 32-bit registers, for variables of type long it must use a pair of registers.  Which are edx:eax for calculations and edi:ebx for storage.

Which is what stands out in the disassembly for the slow version, neither edi nor ebx are used.

When the jitter can't find enough registers to store local variables then it must generate code to load and store them from the stack frame.  That slows down code, it prevents a processor optimization named "register renaming", an internal processor core optimization trick that uses multiple copies of a register and allows super-scalar execution.  Which permits several instructions to run concurrently, even when they use the same register.  Not having enough registers is a common problem on x86 cores, addressed in x64 which has 8 extra registers (r9 through r15).

The jitter will do its best to apply another code generation optimization, it will try to inline your Fibo() method.  In other words, not make a call to the method but generate the code for the method inline in the Main() method.  Pretty important optimization that, for one, makes properties of a C# class for free, giving them the perf of a field.  It avoids the overhead of making the method call and setting up its stack frame, saves a couple of nanoseconds.

There are several rules that determine exactly when a method can be inlined.  They are not exactly documented but have been mentioned in blog posts.  One rule is that it won't happen when the method body is too large.  That defeats the gain from inlining, it generates too much code that doesn't fit as well in the L1 instruction cache.  Another hard rule that applies here is that a method won't be inlined when it contains a try/catch statement.  The background behind that one is an implementation detail of exceptions, they piggy-back onto Windows' built-in support for SEH (Structure Exception Handling) which is stack-frame based.

One behavior of the register allocation algorithm in the jitter can be inferred from playing with this code.  It appears to be aware of when the jitter is trying to inline a method.  One rule it appears to use that only the edx:eax register pair can be used for inlined code that has local variables of type long.  But not edi:ebx.  No doubt because that would be too detrimental to the code generation for the calling method, both edi and ebx are important storage registers.

So you get the fast version because the jitter knows up front that the method body contains try/catch statements.  It knows it can never be inlined so readily uses edi:ebx for storage for the long variable.  You got the slow version because the jitter didn't know up front that inlining wouldn't work.  It only found out *after* generating the code for the method body.

The flaw then is that it didn't go back and *re-generate* the code for the method.  Which is understandable, given the time constraints it has to operate in.

This slow-down doesn't occur on x64 because for one it has 8 more registers.  For another because it can store a long in just one register (like rax).  And the slow-down doesn't occur when you use int instead of long because the jitter has a lot more flexibility in picking registers.

Answer (score 22):

I'd have put this in as a comment as I'm really not certain that this is likely to be the case, but as I recall it doesn't a try/except statement involve a modification to the way the garbage disposal mechanism of the compiler works, in that it clears up object memory allocations in a recursive way off the stack.  There may not be an object to be cleared up in this case or the for loop may constitute a closure that the garbage collection mechanism recognises sufficient to enforce a different collection method.
Probably not, but I thought it worth a mention as I hadn't seen it discussed anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

9 years later and the bug is still there!  You can see it easily with:

```
   static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      int hundredMillion = 1000000;
      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
      double sqrt;
      for (int i=0; i < hundredMillion; i++)
      {
        sqrt = Math.Sqrt( DateTime.Now.ToOADate() );
      }
      DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

      double sqrtMs = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;

      Console.WriteLine( "Elapsed milliseconds: " + sqrtMs );

      DateTime start2 = DateTime.Now;

      double sqrt2;
      for (int i = 0; i < hundredMillion; i++)
      {
        try
        {
          sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt( DateTime.Now.ToOADate() );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          int br = 0;
        }
      }
      DateTime end2 = DateTime.Now;

      double sqrtMsTryCatch = (end2 - start2).TotalMilliseconds;

      Console.WriteLine( "Elapsed milliseconds: " + sqrtMsTryCatch );

      Console.WriteLine( "ratio is " + sqrtMsTryCatch / sqrtMs );

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The ratio is less than one on my machine, running the latest version of MSVS 2019, .NET 4.6.1

Comment: I ran this code in .NET 5.0. On x86 it takes between 530-535 ms without a try-catch and between 1-3% less with try-catch. When building x64 it takes between 218-222 ms without try-catch and between 11-13% less with try-catch. How curious.

Comment: FYI: It's better to use `Stopwatch` to measure performance.

Comment: I used to use stopwatch, but I did not notice any advantages

Comment: Even better than Stopwatch is [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html)