# Any easy way to cast List<int?> to List<int>

Tags: c#, .net

At the moment I use `List<int> ints = tuple.Item2.Select(s => s.Value).ToList()` but this looks inefficient when tuple.Item2 has 1000's of items. Any better way to achieve this? except using a for loop.

Comment: ^  Konstantin, it is - however its a real good question. @ Jack - This is better for "Code Review"

Comment: Besides your code does not reflect the situation when `s.HasValue == false`...

Comment: Are you guaranteed that all objects will have a value?

Comment: @ Maurice - hes not. CODE REVIEW TOPIC NOT STACK !!!

Comment: @Maurico: Yes. Next question from Konstanin would be so why use List<int?>. Answer is I have to because it is returned from 3rd party lib.

Comment: @Jack so you should consider that it may contain `null`, shouldn't you?

Comment: no, it doesn't. It never returns null. Don't know why the lib developer used List<int?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in way to convert each element in one `List<T1>` and store the result in another `List<T2>` is [`List<T1>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
List<int> ints = tuple.Item2.ConvertAll(s => s.Value);
```

Unlike `.Select(...).ToList()` or `.Cast(...).ToList()`, this method knows the list size in advance, and prevents unnecessary reallocations that `.ToList()` cannot avoid.

For this to work, `tuple.Item2` must really be a `List<int?>`. It's not an extension method, it cannot work on the generic `IEnumerable<int?>` interface.

Comment: It could be that `s => s.GetValueOrDefault()` is faster than just `s => s.Value`. This may seem surprising, but the reason is that `.GetValueOrDefault()` always and unconditionally exposes the backing field (`value`), while the `.Value` property first checks the Boolean field (`hasValue`) to see if it is true or false, and only then exposes that backing field (or throws if `hasValue` was false). The `Nullable<>` struct ensures that the backing field always has its default value in the case where we are modeling a "null", so that is why the behavior of `.GetValueOrDefault()` is safe.

Comment: You can also write it as `s => s ?? 0`.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use Linq `Cast<>` to achieve this .

```
List<int> ints = tuple.Item2.Cast<int>();
```

but if an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw an exception.you have to consider catching exception.

Comment: +1 but what about efficiency? You cannot do better than O(n) with cast anyway, I think. And you have to do `.Where(x => x.HasValue)` to check nulls

Comment: You still need a `ToList()` on the end.

Comment: Also this is slower than the original code by a factor of 3 for 200000 items.

Comment: @mikez: Really? It looks better than original. I assume built in extension method would be faster. I will test this.

Comment: @RomanPekar & mike you are right.but i have suggested the way to deceive some one it is efficient :)

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili: Deceiving is not what I expected but thanks :)

Comment: @Jack i was just kidding.you'r code will be even more efficient if you put it inside try - catch.if you don't believe me check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928403/try-catch-speeding-up-my-code\