# Mvc Basic debugging on the basis of razor ccode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
var roles = ViewData["Roles"] as List<ABC.XYZ.Customs.CustomRole>;
```

This code snippet is in razor and I am trying to debug that why roles is coming null how to do that. I am very new to MVC

Comment: go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160127/whats-the-point-of-as-keyword-in-c-sharp) it may help you

Comment: Paste your controller code call where you add role to **viewdata**