# Clear all controls in a ASP.NET page with a Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net page which is inherited from a master page .I want to clear all controls in this page .I tried using  the bellow method .This is not working if a master page is there. Otherwise its working fine any ideas?

```
private void ClearControls()
{
    foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to clear the TextBoxes in both the Page and its MasterPage, or is it simply not clearing the TextBoxes in your Page when you use a MasterPage with it?

Comment: This might've to do with where you call ClearControls() from ...

Comment: Why isn't it working if a MasterPage is there? Whats the exception? What does the quickwatch show about Page.Controls?

Comment: it simply not clearing the TextBoxes in your Page when you use a MasterPage with it.I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
public void FindAllTextBox(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)c).Text = string.empty;
            FindAllTextBox(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Ex.:

```
Control ctrl = this.FindControl("content");
FindAllTextBox(ctrl);
```

Comment: Compare types directly is bad idea. There are operators `as` and `is` for that. Much faster and more properly

Comment: you can clear all textboxes with this function...

FindAllTextBox(this);

Comment: Use operator `as`, instead of `is` and `cast`

Comment: i think there is no difference between cast and as.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with `Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls`:

```
foreach (Control item in Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls)
{
    if (item is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)item).Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of your controls are inside of another container when you add a master page. Have you tried adding another foreach before if?

```
private void ClearControls()
{ 
    foreach(Control container in Page.Controls) 
    {  
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)  
        {     
            foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)  
            {     
                if (ctrl is TextBox)        
                {          
                    ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty; 
                }   
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't do it this way though. Sometimes hardcoding is better. This would use a lot of resource when called on a page that contains lots of controls.

Comment: Use operator `as`, instead of `is` and `cast`

Comment: is there any case that this would result in an exception? I guess not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-as-operator-so-popular

Comment: I know the difference between as and is yet control can never be null in this example because of the if check.

Comment: This is the question of performance. And best practice. You do a superfluous operation.

Comment: I would NEVER loop through all controls in a page as I stated in my answer. I'm sure that would suck more resource than a few casting. :)

Comment: Don't hard code! Get recursive instead. See code posted below (or possibly above).

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard code:

```
//Recursively get all the formControls underneath the current one, be it Page, UserControl or whatever.
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)  
{  
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)  
    {
        yield return control;  
        foreach (Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())  
        {  
            yield return descendant;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Then you can call it in your webform / control:

```
var formCtls = this.GetAllControls().OfType<TextBox>();
foreach(TextBox txtbx in formCtls)
{
    //do what you gotta do ;)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use operator `as` instead of `is` and `cast`:

```
TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    tb.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Second, you can use `ITextControl` instead of `TextBox`.

And third, try next extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControls(this Control control) where T : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<T>() : Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var c in this.Page.Controls.GetChildControls<TextBox>())
{
    c.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I think I was making it too hard.  I'm using an AJAX UpdatePanel control and I just referenced that instead of going all the way up to the MasterPage. This worked for me.

```
        foreach (Control c in UpdatePanel1.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control c1 in c.Controls)
            {
                if (c1 is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)c1;
                    txtBox.Text = "0";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the controls in Panel, and try the code below

```
foreach (Control cntrl in pnl.Controls)//pnl is panel id  
                {  
                    if (cntrl is TextBox)  
                    {  
                        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)cntrl;  
                        txtBox.Text = " ";  
                    }  
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a method on your .cs like this:

```
 //Where "this" is Page.
 ClearInput(this);

 private void ClearInput(Control parent)
 {
     foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
     {
          if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
                ClearInput(c);
          else
          {
               if (c is TextBox)
                  (c as TextBox).Text = "";

               if (c is CheckBox)
                  (c as CheckBox).Checked = false;

                if (c is DropDownList)
                   (c as DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 1;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: wont work if you use this in a control residing on a page that is on master page.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void EnableControls(Control control)
        {
            var textbox = control as TextBox;
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.Enabled = true;
            }

            var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
            if (dropDownList != null)
            {
                dropDownList.Enabled = true;
            }

            var radioButton = control as RadioButton;
            if (radioButton != null)
            {
                radioButton.Enabled = true;
            }

            var checkBox = control as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox != null)
            {
                checkBox.Enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
            {
                EnableControls(childControl);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been nice, here, to help someone coming across this post later understand it, and why it might be an answer to the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void getAllCtl(ControlCollection ctls)
    {

        foreach (Control c in ctls)
        {
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            {
                //TextBox tt = c as TextBox;
                ////to do something by using textBox tt.
                ((TextBox)c).Text = string.Empty;
            }
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
            {
                ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
            }
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
            {
                ((DropDownList)c).SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                getAllCtl(c.Controls);

            }
        }

    }
```

calling in aspx.cs file as

```
        getAllCtl(this.Form.Controls);
```

This is OK and tested work for all Master-child page and where ever multiple controls are contains in the page...