# The "is" keyword: there a difference in these methods?

Tags: c#

Not really sure about the `is` keyword, but I *think* these two are the same.  Can anyone confirm this?

```
public bool Equals(Object obj)
{ 
   if (obj == null) return false;
   MyType t = (MyType)obj;
   if (t == null) return false;
   return true;
}
```

and the other is...

```
public bool Equals(Object obj)
{ 
   return obj is MyType;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are definitely not equal. The cast to `(MyType)` will throw `InvalidCastException` immediately if `obj` isn't an instance of `MyType`.  The expression will not evaluate to `null` if the cast fails. `as` operator exhibits the behavior you are expecting from that cast. [My answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-sharp-as-operator-so-popular/2139818#2139818) discusses this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same. If `obj` is not `MyType`, the first version throws an exception, the second version returns `false`.

And this implementation of `Equals()` is quite strange. Are you sure you want to consider all instances of `MyType` as equal?

Comment: definitely not - it was only intended as a quick example

Answer (score 2):

In the first method, you risk the cast failing and throwing an exception. I think you might be mixed up with the `as` keyword, which returns `null` if the cast fails instead. Once that's fixed, the methods would be roughly equivalent:

```
public bool Equals(Object obj)
{ 
   return (obj as MyType) != null;
}
```

But the latter is more concise and clear anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not the same, the 1st version bombs with an InvalidCastException if an object of an unrelated type is passed.

Equals() is supposed to test for value equality, not type equality.

Answer (score 1):

> An is expression evaluates to true if both of the following conditions
>   are met:
>
> expression is not null.
>
> expression can be cast to type.
>
> That is, a cast expression of the form (type)(expression) will complete without
>   throwing an exception. For more information, see 7.6.6 Cast
>   expressions. A compile-time warning will be issued if the expression
>   expression is type is known to always be true or always be false.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The methods are not the same.  If `obj` is not of `MyType` it will throw an exception while `is` will not, it will return `false`.