# C#, Is it possible to recast an object and access methods and properties without creating new object variable

Tags: c#, object, methods, casting

C#, Is it possible to recast an object and access methods and properties without creating new object variable?

For example:

```
foreach (object o in collection)
{
    if (o is MyType)
        {
            (MyType)o.MyProperty = x
        }
 }
```

Currently, I have to re-cast o to another variable of MyType [ex: MyType m = (MyType)o ] in order to access methods or properties of MyType.  It seems wasteful, so I'm wondering if I'm missing some mechanic that will allow me to skip the declaration of a new object variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "wasteful". It's not like the compiler does something special because you declare a local variable that it would not do if you merely said `((MyType)o).MyProperty`.

Also, `is` and cast is frowned upon. Use `as` instead and check for nullity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/why-is-the-c-sharp-as-operator-so-popular/2139818#2139818

Comment: Why do you consider it wasteful? Do you mean it's overly verbose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `.` has higher precedence than the cast. So you need to add parentheses:

```
foreach (object o in collection) 
{ 
    if (o is MyType) 
        { 
            ((MyType)o).MyProperty = x; 
        } 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq:

```
foreach(MyType t in collection.OfType<MyType>()) {}
```

You can also use direct casting:

```
foreach(object o in collection)
{
    if(o is MyType)
    {
        ((MyType)o).MyProperty = x;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively if you you *know* or want to make sure (keep in mind an `InvalidCastException` would be possible if the collection is mixed types), you can use the `Cast` Linq method:

```
// If your collection is all of the same type
foreach(MyType t in collection.Cast<MyType>()) {}
```

Comment: You'd be wanting `OfType` here, not `Cast`, to prevent an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens The OP's code fits `OfType`, not `Cast` since he's checking if the type fits with `is`.

Comment: @Christopher I know, but the OP is explicitly checking for `if (x is T)` which implies that the collection might contain other elements as well, which makes `Cast` choke.

Comment: Thank you, yes the collection is of mixed types and I'm trying to avoid InvalidCastExceptions.  And, by "wasteful" I simply meant that it's an extra line of code that may not be necessary.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2):

You need two pairs of parentheses.

```
((MyType)o).MyProperty = x;
```

Otherwise the casting is applied to the whole expression.

---

```
y = (MyType)o.MyMethod(x);
```

is the same as

```
y = (MyType)(o.MyMethod(x));
```

which is not what you want (it casts the result of `MyMethod`). Instead write

```
y = ((MyType)o).MyMethod(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can cast

```
foreach(var t in collection.Cast<YourType>())
{
  t.MyProperty = x;
}
```

Nota : but you must know that boxing or unboxing operation are expensive operation in your memory, when you pass from reference type to value type , or  value type to reference type.

In this case you don't have this constraints.

Answer (score 0):

implement an Interface

```
interface MyInterface
{
 string MyProperty;
}

foreach(object o in collection)
{
MyInterface o= originalObject as MyInterface

if (MyInterface!= null)

  ((MyInterface)o).MyProperty = x;
}
```