# How can I modify a member of an object list with a common superclass in C#?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I implement a WindowsForms application in Visual Studio. Now I have a list of toys:

```
List <Toy> toys;
```

`Toy` is an abstract class, and classes like `Car`, `Submarine` etc. derive from it. The list can of course contain any object of type `Toy`. Due to my lack of experience in C#, I'm not sure how can I modify an object from this list, i. e. change a property that is type-specific. The compiler only knows the list contains `Toy` objects, and has no access to fields of a `Submarine` object. So I cannot simply take some element from the list, call a setter and be done with it. Casting will only get me a copy of the list object cast to some type. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that casting does *not* copy the item.

Comment: Can you post your `Toy` class? It with result in a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast items :

```
Engine door = toys.OfType<Car>().Select(c => c.Engine).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: and now modifying the `door` object will also permanently modify the corresponding list entry?

Comment: Yes. Now it's an engine, but yes ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not savvy with Lync or want to do more with the item, you can also do it the 'old school' way in a loop.

Given the sample classes:

```
public abstract class Toy
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Elephant : Toy
{
    public int TrunkLength { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Toy
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

You can do something like this to add the items and then modify them based on their type:

```
var toys = new List<Toy>
{
    new Car {Color = Color.Red, Manufacturer = "HotWheels"},
    new Elephant {TrunkLength = 36, Manufacturer = "Steiff Harlequin"}
};

foreach (var toy in toys)
{
    var car = toy as Car;
    if (car != null)
    {
        // Set properties or call methods on the car here
        car.Color = Color.Blue;

        // Continue the loop
        continue;
    }

    var elephant = toy as Elephant;
    if (elephant != null)
    {
        // Do something with the elephant object
        elephant.TrunkLength = 48;

        // Continue the loop
        continue;
    }
}
```

Or you could use a 'switch' statement and some casting, which may be more readable:

```
foreach (var toy in toys)
{
    switch (toy.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "Car":
            ((Car) toy).Color = Color.Blue;
            break;
        case "Elephant":
            var elephant = toy as Elephant;
            elephant.TrunkLength = 48;
            elephant.Manufacturer = "Made in China";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So... You basically have a situation like this?

```
public abstract class Toy 
{ 
}

public class Submarine : Toy 
{ 
    public bool IsOccupiedByPretendPeople { get; set; } 
}
```

And you also have

```
List<Toy> toys;
```

And you want to get all the instances of a `Submarine` class?

This should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<Submarine> submarines = toys.OfType<Submarine>();
```

If you posted an example of your `Toy` class (as mentioned in the comments of your question), I could further assist you with what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

When we have an inheritance family and we need to use specific feature from one of the subtypes we can also use the is operator: here is an example

public abstract class Toy
    {
    }

```
public class Submarine : Toy
{
}

public class Airwolf : Toy
{

    public Boolean ActivateMissiles()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Toy> myToys = new List<Toy>();
        myToys.Add(new Submarine());
        myToys.Add(new Airwolf());

        // Looking for airwolves
        foreach (Toy t in myToys)
        {
            if (t is Airwolf)
            {
                Airwolf myWolf = (Airwolf)t;
                myWolf.ActivateMissiles();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `as` plus `!= null` check over `is`. For more info, check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139798/does-it-make-sense-to-use-as-instead-of-a-cast-even-if-there-is-no-null-check